# FireFox doesn't start by Selenium

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-firefoxdriver

I Can't start FireFox by selenium.

When I make a FirefoxDriver instance,the error open.

```
public void startFireFox() {
    driver = new FirefoxDriver();
}
```

The firefox window is white page.Like the Img.
[![enter image description here][1]][1]

Error log is like this. How can I resolve the problem?

```
Build info: version: '2.47.1', revision: '411b314', time: '2015-07-30 02:56:46'
System info: os.name: 'Windows 8.1', os.ar
ch: 'x86', os.version: '6.3', java.version: '1.8.0_60'
Driver info: driver.version: FirefoxDriver
        at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.internal.NewProfileExtensionConnection.st
art(NewProfileExtensionConnection.java:134)
        at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.startClient(FirefoxDriver.j
ava:276)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.jav
a:116)
        at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:2
23)
        at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:2
16)
        at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:2
12)
        at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:1
25)
        at org.selenium.Browser.startFireFox(Browser.java:251)
        at com.buyma.NewDisplay.initialSetting(NewDisplay.java:77)
        at com.buyma.NewDisplayTool.actionPerformed(NewDisplayTool.java:130)
        at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
        at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)
        at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
        at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(Unknown Source)
        at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(Unknown Sour
ce)
        at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
        at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionP
rivilege(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionP
rivilege(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionP
rivilege(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.firefox.NotConnectedException: Unable to connect
to host 127.0.0.1 on port 7055 after 45000 ms. Firefox console output:
"appDisabled":false,"descriptor":"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Mozilla Firefox\\brow
ser\\extensions\\{972ce4c6-7e08-4474-a285-3208198ce6fd}","installDate":144390787
7310,"updateDate":1443907877310,"applyBackgroundUpdates":1,"skinnable":true,"siz
e":22852,"sourceURI":null,"releaseNotesURI":null,"softDisabled":false,"foreignIn
stall":false,"hasBinaryComponents":false,"strictCompatibility":true,"locales":[]
,"targetApplications":[{"id":"{ec8030f7-c20a-464f-9b0e-13a3a9e97384}","minVersio
n":"41.0.1","maxVersion":"41.0.1"}],"targetPlatforms":[]}
1444033838736   addons.xpi      DEBUG   getModTime: Recursive scan of {972ce4c6-
7e08-4474-a285-3208198ce6fd}
1444033838740   addons.xpi      DEBUG   Updating database with changes to instal
led add-ons
1444033838740   addons.xpi-utils        DEBUG   Updating add-on states
1444033838742   addons.xpi-utils        DEBUG   Writing add-ons list
1444033838788   addons.manager  DEBUG   Registering shutdown blocker for XPIProv
ider
1444033838789   addons.manager  DEBUG   Provider finished startup: XPIProvider
1444033838789   addons.manager  DEBUG   Starting provider: LightweightThemeManag
er
1444033838790   addons.manager  DEBUG   Registering shutdown blocker for Lightwe
ightThemeManager
1444033838790   addons.manager  DEBUG   Provider finished startup: LightweightTh
emeManager
1444033838791   addons.manager  DEBUG   Starting provider: GMPProvider
1444033838802   addons.manager  DEBUG   Registering shutdown blocker for GMPProv
ider
1444033838802   addons.manager  DEBUG   Provider finished startup: GMPProvider
1444033838802   addons.manager  DEBUG   Starting provider: PluginProvider
1444033838802   addons.manager  DEBUG   Registering shutdown blocker for PluginP
rovider
1444033838803   addons.manager  DEBUG   Provider finished startup: PluginProvide
r
1444033838803   addons.manager  DEBUG   Completed startup sequence
1444033840197   addons.manager  DEBUG   Starting provider: <unnamed-provider>
1444033840197   addons.manager  DEBUG   Registering shutdown blocker for <unname
d-provider>
1444033840198   addons.manager  DEBUG   Provider finished startup: <unnamed-prov
ider>
1444033841030   DeferredSave.extensions.json    DEBUG   Starting write
1444033841636   addons.repository       DEBUG   No addons.json found.
1444033841637   DeferredSave.addons.json        DEBUG   Save changes
1444033841642   DeferredSave.addons.json        DEBUG   Starting timer
1444033841680   addons.manager  DEBUG   Starting provider: PreviousExperimentPro
vider
1444033841680   addons.manager  DEBUG   Registering shutdown blocker for Previou
sExperimentProvider
1444033841681   addons.manager  DEBUG   Provider finished startup: PreviousExper
imentProvider
1444033841705   DeferredSave.extensions.json    DEBUG   Write succeeded
1444033841706   addons.xpi-utils        DEBUG   XPI Database saved, setting sche
ma version preference to 17
1444033841707   DeferredSave.addons.json        DEBUG   Starting write
1444033841764   DeferredSave.addons.json        DEBUG   Write succeeded
JavaScript error: file:///C:/Users/%E5%B6%BA%E5%90%BE/AppData/Local/Temp/anonymo
us3133745447996684817webdriver-profile/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/compon
ents/bad-cert-listener.js, line 2245: NS_ERROR_FAILURE: Component returned failu
re code: 0x80004005 (NS_ERROR_FAILURE) [nsILocalFile.createUnique]
JavaScript error: chrome://fxdriver/content/server.js, line 61: NS_ERROR_XPC_CI_
RETURNED_FAILURE: Component returned failure code: 0x80570015 (NS_ERROR_XPC_CI_R
ETURNED_FAILURE) [nsIJSCID.createInstance]
1444033854172   addons.manager  DEBUG   shutdown
1444033854173   addons.manager  DEBUG   Calling shutdown blocker for XPIProvider

1444033854173   addons.xpi      DEBUG   shutdown
1444033854174   addons.xpi-utils        DEBUG   shutdown
1444033854175   addons.manager  DEBUG   Calling shutdown blocker for Lightweight
ThemeManager
1444033854176   addons.manager  DEBUG   Calling shutdown blocker for GMPProvider

1444033854179   addons.manager  DEBUG   Calling shutdown blocker for PluginProvi
der
1444033854180   addons.manager  DEBUG   Calling shutdown blocker for <unnamed-pr
ovider>
1444033854183   addons.manager  DEBUG   Calling shutdown blocker for PreviousExp
erimentProvider
1444033854190   addons.xpi      DEBUG   Notifying XPI shutdown observers
1444033854198   addons.manager  DEBUG   Async provider shutdown done

        at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.internal.NewProfileExtensionConnection.st
art(NewProfileExtensionConnection.java:122)
        ... 45 more
```

Comment: Does `driver.get("some_URL_here");` do anything to the browser?

Answer (score 0):

Its the compatibility issue between Selenium Webdriver version that you are using **('2.47.1')** and Firefox version **("41.0.1")**. I have experienced the same problem with a previous version of Webdriver and at that time, downgrading the Firefox version helped. Please check the [changelog](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/d8359a1a406af1ea6366662265fe172ae1a1e723/java/CHANGELOG) for Selenium Webdriver or use link CHANGELOG from [here](http://www.seleniumhq.org/download/) and use supported version of Firefox.

Comment: edited my answer to reflect changelog for Selenium-Java

Answer (score 0):

This is a very common issue which is faced by the beginners need not to worry, better to import the last selenium API i.e 2.47.1 or if you are using the older version of selenium API try with **Mozilla lower version like Mozilla version 31. I guarantee it will work.**

Comment: Thank you for your response. But unfortunately I'm using API ver 2.47.1.  Do you have any idea?

Build info: version: '2.47.1', revision: '411b314', time: '2015-07-30 02:56:46'
System info: os.name: 'Windows 8.1', os.ar

Comment: I tried Mozilla version 31. But I got same error... This error happen only this pc.

Comment: If still your issue is not fixed need not to worry dear i am ready to help. please find my email id :- shukla.imcl@gmai.com, let me know if i can take team viewer of your system and solve the issue.